# Change UIBarButtonItem from UISearchBar

Tags: swift, ios8, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, uicolor

I'd like to change the text font and color of the Cancel button inside the UISearchBar in iOS 8. I've tried the solutions for iOS 6 and 7 already and they don't seem to work.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 5):

This was not the solution I was looking for, but it worked.

```
let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: FONT_REGULAR_16!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: COLOR_BLUE]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: this is working for me also.  minor revision for swift 2 with the font attribute and constants removed.   -

let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
       UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: This changes the color of all bar button items, not only the Cancel button of the UISearchBar.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```
//The tintColor below will change the colour of the cancel button
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

But these are also useful While we are on the subject:

```
searchBar.placeholder = "Placeholder"
//The barTintColor changes the colour of the flashing text indicator
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
//This sets the cancel button to show up
searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
//This makes the searchBar become active 
searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```